# Cant link alexa to foursquare API

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

Hey there how would I link the foursquare api to my alexa app? Could someone maybe provide some guidance or assistance. I'm feeling pretty lost right now.
Thanks!

Comment: which endpoint are you going to use? What is the use case? You should use foursquare docs - https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/places-api/getting-started/#make-your-first-api-call (Node.js) sample. About async api calls -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/62194165/2823106

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to link the foursquare api. Essentially just add all the client secret and id's where alexa wants you to. Then for domains you enter cdn.foursquare.com. And for authorize and token you fill out https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate and https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token respectively. Alexa handels filling out the client id and redirect uri for you. You just have to enter the intial urls.